# Use mutt to check local e-mail?

Tags: mutt

I have been using `mutt` for my e-mail for quite some time now. I tried to install a bug-tracking system but it sends an e-mail confirmation for the login to the local user (i.e. root@localhost).

How can I have the local e-mail routed so I see it in my mutt inbox?

Comment: Note that the specifics of the answer to this question depends on the MDA (e.g. procmail) and MTA (e.g. Exim, Postfix) you have installed, not the MUA (i.e. mutt).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the file `.forward` on the home directory of root and add the other user name in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

To forward `root`'s email to some other local user (e.g. `me`), you can put the following line in the [`/etc/aliases/`](http://linux.about.com/od/lna_guide/a/gdelna152t01.htm) file:

```
root: me
```

When you open Mutt as `me`, it will check `me`'s mailbox. If for some reason `me`'s mailbox is in a non-standard location (e.g. `~/my_local_mail`), then when you launch Mutt, you will need to tell Mutt the mailbox's location:

```
mutt -f ~/my_local_mail
```